firebase deploy hosting in GitHub Actions - Failed to authenticate - Self-hosted runner
With GitHub Actions in a GitHub Organization (free plan). This plan gives me insufficient minutes for my pipelines, so a colleague (not in the company anymore) set up a linux self-hosted runner and it's been running great, taking care of the jobs.
We've started a Flutter project, and need macOS to build the app for iOS. So I took out an available iMac and set up a macOS runner to take care of jobs for these specific project.
Now... when the Mac is idle I would like it to share the workload that the other runner could have, but I've been having some trouble with firebase deploy. This is the error thrown in the GitHubActions logs
Run FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
Verifying firebase.json exists
Setting up CLI credentials
Deploying to production site
...
/[macOS runner path]/actions-runner/_work/_tool/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/npx firebase-tools@v12.9.1 deploy --only hosting --project ****** --json
  npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: firebase-tools@12.9.1
  npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
  npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
  npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
  {
    "status": "error",
    "error": "Failed to authenticate, have you run \u001b[1mfirebase login\u001b[22m?"
  }{
    "status": "error",
    "error": "Failed to authenticate, have you run \u001b[1mfirebase login\u001b[22m?"
  }
  The process '/[macOS runner path]/actions-runner/_work/_tool/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/npx' failed with exit code 1
  Retrying deploy with the --debug flag for better error output
  /[macOS runner path]/actions-runner/_work/_tool/node/16.20.2/x64/bin/npx firebase-tools@v12.9.1 deploy --only hosting --project ***** --debug
  npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: firebase-tools@12.9.1
  [2024-05-08T22:13:06.324Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
  [2024-05-08T22:13:06.544Z] FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token: read ECONNRESET
      at Gunzip.<anonymous> (/[user path]/.npm/_npx/f11742b8b7a1393f/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:400:12)
      at Gunzip.emit (node:events:525:35)
      at Gunzip.emit (node:domain:489:12)
      at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
      at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
  
  Error: Failed to authenticate, have you run firebase login?
  [2024-05-08T22:13:06.324Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
  [2024-05-08T22:13:06.544Z] FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token: read ECONNRESET
      at Gunzip.<anonymous> (/[User path]/.npm/_npx/f11742b8b7a1393f/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:400:12)
      at Gunzip.emit (node:events:525:35)
      at Gunzip.emit (node:domain:489:12)
      at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
      at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
  
  Error: Failed to authenticate, have you run firebase login?

What am I missing? why doesn't this happen in the linux runner? is there some extra configuration that should be done in a macOS runner?
